# Program control goes out and lost after downloading excel/word functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net, scriptmanager

I have a C# program which will be used to download a generated word document. Also, after generating it, the 'Hour Glass' property in UI has to be reset to default. For that I am calling one javascript function using scriptmanager, which can be executed only if the statement appears at the last. Unfortunately, a step before there is a code to download the word document. when it happens, the program gets lost and never goes back and execute the remaining part of the program in which the script manager is present to stop the hourglass. Putting script manager ahead of the downloading code also wont help. I suffer a lot from this peculiar problem. Please help, Thank you!!

Below is the code.,

```
private void DownloadFile(string filename)
{
        System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(filename);
        if (file.Exists)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.FullName);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "Application/msword";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
            //HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "stopHourglass()", true);
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you `try` to `catch` a possible `exception` in the relavant code block? An exception may get supressed, depending on the calling context...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically; you can't do this. You can only send one response to the client at a time. It's either the file or page update, you can't have both.  You've also got `response.end` in there, telling the script to effectively stop.

I suggest you drop the javascript to display the hour glass

Answer (score 0):

When `Response.End()` is called, you will no longer get a response back from the server because `Response.End()` throws an exception by nature and you can do nothing about it. What you need to do is switch the order. Once you have your file ready to download, use `ScriptManager` to register a script that does `__doPostBack` with a particular argument. Later in `Page_Load` you will read that argument and execute the download accordingly. Meanwhile, after `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` (or `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock`), Do your clean up logic.

The Code will look like the following:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "DownloadFileKey", "__doPostBack('', '" + YourArgumentConstStr + "');", true);
// You clean up code here.
```

And in Page_Load:

```
if (Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] != null && Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] == YourArgumentConstStr)
   // Download the file here.
```

Now your next question will be: Is that the 'neatest' possible way to do it? Basically, if you insist on having everything on the same page then yes you'll have to implement such a workaround. However, the general trend is to open up another tab (new page) that only does the download. One popular example is Microsoft website. Check how you download .NET Framework [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42642).

Comment: @yazanpro..It seems a nice idea, I tried in  the same way, I m calling the scriptmanager first, which calls javascript function in which i have written  the code as follows.,                                                                                                                   function doPostBack(message) {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'auto';
        alert("calling page load again!!");
        __doPostBack('Page_Load', message);
        
     }

Comment: This function gets called, i have also kept breakpoint in page load, but what happens is, when the _dopostback line gets executed it never goes to the page load of that page, but the page gets refreshed..Really weird how the page gets refreshed but am not able to catch the event with breakpoint in page load...any idea for this?

Comment: No first argument should be passed in __doPostBack ( no 'Page_Load') unless you have an update panel then you can pass its id as the first argument to produce a partcial post back. Stick to the sample code I provided and see if it works. Then you can tweak it if you need to.